# Regex - match behind an optional character

Tags: regex

I want to match a string that has more than 3 characters and combine with positive look behind an optional character (/).
From the input:

```
100/ABC-12345 10
ABCD
ZZZ
```

I need to retrieve:

```
ABC-12345 10
ABCD
```

I can match them separately but cannot combine them. See [my current regex](https://regex101.com/r/jihOsd/1):

```
(?<=\/).*
```

Comment: What is the programming environment? .NET? Python? Should `ABCD/S1` be matched?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am not entirely sure but I believe that it's java. Yes ABCD has 4 characters (>3) so should be matched.

Comment: As I understand you wish to match 4 or more characters that start at the beginning of the string or that follow a forward slash. That presumably includes `'AB/C'` in `'100/AB/C'` (but if it doesn't that needs to be clarified). Your first sentence should just include a statement of the problem and should not be co-mingled with a reference to the technique you think needs to be employed (positive lookbehind).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks I will keep a note next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
(?<=/|^)\w[\w-]{3,}
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jihOsd/2)

Positive lookbehind `(?<=/|^)` asserts presence of `/` or start of line behind current position and `\w[\w-]{3,}` matches at least 4 of  word or hyphen characters where first character must be a word character.

Comment: Thanks! I need to match the space (in ABC-12345 10) so I made 1 small change to your regex `(?<=/|^)\w[\w\- ]{3,}` and it seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/?[\w-]{4,}
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/4TOhGZlKkHYV4Z).

This matches a slash optionally, then at least 4 of word chars or dashes.

Comment: Thanks but I would need to exclude the slash too